# Spawn number of GameObjects randomly around a circle at a minimum distance from each other

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently I have two balls that spawn randomly around a circle, with a minimum distance of 0.3 between them so they do not collide. However, I want the player to set the amount of balls to spawn, and I need these balls to spawn randomly but with a minimum amount of distance from each other.

With my code, any ball amount that is greater than 2 may have a chance of two balls spawning on top of each other, since I only reference the position of the last spawned ball with `spawnConstant`.

When I tried to figure it out with arrays, I ran into the same problem, having the position only refer to one position in the array. Attached is the current code:

```
IEnumerator SpawnBalls () {

    Vector3 spawnConstant = new Vector3 ();
    Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3 ();

    for (int i = 0; i < ballNumber; i++) {

        if (i == 0) {

            spawnPosition = Random.insideUnitCircle.normalized * 0.7f; 
            Instantiate (ball, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
            Debug.Log ("wolo");
            spawnConstant = spawnPosition;

        } else if (i > 0) {

            spawnPosition = Random.insideUnitCircle.normalized * 0.7f;

            while (Vector3.Distance (spawnPosition, spawnConstant) <= 0.3f) {
                spawnPosition = Random.insideUnitCircle.normalized * 0.7f;
            }

            spawnConstant = spawnPosition;
            Instantiate (ball, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
            Debug.Log ("yolo");
        }
    }
    yield return null;
}
```

How can I make each ball refer to the positions of all the previous ones and spawn a minimum distance away from them?

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerator SpawnBalls () {

    Vector3[] ballArray = new Vector3[ballNumber];
    Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3 ();

    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < ballNumber; i++) {

        // Create first ball and store coordinates into our ballArray at index 0
        if (i == 0) {

            spawnPosition = Random.insideUnitCircle.normalized * 0.7f; 
            Instantiate (ball, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
            Debug.Log ("wolo");
            ballArray[index] = spawnPosition;

        // Else we already have one ball
        } else if (i > 0) {
            // Create new spawn coordinates
            spawnPosition = Random.insideUnitCircle.normalized * 0.7f;

            // Loop through indicies of array that have been filled
            for( int k = 0; k <= index; k++ ) {
              // Check that each value in array meets distance requirement
              if(Vector3.Distance (spawnPosition, ballArray[k]) <= 0.3f) {
                // If not, create new coordinates and reset k
                spawnPosition = Random.insideUnitCircle.normalized * 0.7f;
                k = 0;
            }

            // Update array
            ballArray[index++] = spawnPosition;

            Instantiate (ball, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
            Debug.Log ("yolo");
        }
        }
        yield return null;
    }
```